# Actions affecting all data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My application performs a fetch to retrieve data from a MongoDb. It displays the data as desired. However actions being performed on data is affecting all of it rather than individually. For example when a title is clicked (clickHandler) the rest of the properties associated to that title should display. These should all work independently but instead clicking on any title displays all properties for every title being returned. Anyone any idea what i am missing here?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import GoogleSearch from "./GoogleSerach";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchSubjects } from "../../actions/subject";

class Subject extends Component {
  // on loading the subjects will be fetched
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchSubjects();
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      viewDescription: false,
      viewSummary: false,
    };
  }

  // add new subject to the top of subjects
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.newPost) {
      this.props.subjects.unshift(nextProps.newPost);
    }
  }

  clickHandler() {
    this.setState({ viewDescription: !this.state.viewDescription });
    console.log("Clicked");
  }

  hoverHandler() {
    // this.setState({ viewSummary: true });
    console.log("Hovered");
  }

  hoverOffHandler() {
    // this.setState({ viewSummary: false });
    console.log("Hovered off");
  }

  render() {
    var view = this.state.viewDescription ? "" : "none";
    var hover = this.state.viewSummary ? "" : "none";
    const subjectItems = this.props.subjects.map((subject) => (
      <div key={subject._id}>
        <div
          className="subjectTitle"
          onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}
          onMouseEnter={this.hoverHandler}
          onMouseLeave={this.hoverOffHandler}
        >
          <p className="title">{subject.title}</p>
          <p className="rating">Rating: {subject.rating}</p>
        </div>

        <p className="summary" style={{ display: hover }}>
          {subject.summary}
        </p>

        <div className="subjectBody " style={{ display: view }}>
          <div className="subjectAuthor">
            <p className="author">
              Subject created by: {subject.author} on {subject.date}
            </p>
            <a href="">
              <div className="buttonRateSubject">RATE SUBJECT</div>
            </a>
          </div>

          <div className="subjectDescription">
            <p className="description">{subject.description}</p>
          </div>

          <div className="subjectLinks">Links:</div>

          <div className="subjectComments">
            <p>Comments:</p>
            <p>{subject.comments}</p>
            <a href="/addcomment">
              <div className="buttonAddComment">ADD COMMENT</div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div id="Subject">
        <GoogleSearch />
        {subjectItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Subject.propTypes = {
  fetchSubjects: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  subjects: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  newPost: PropTypes.object,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  subjects: state.subjects.items,
  newSubject: state.subjects.item,
});

// export default Subject;
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchSubjects })(Subject);
```

Comment: Maybe try to change this -> `...map((subject, i) => ( <div key={i} > ...)`

Comment: @Vova it doesn't have to do with the `key` prop, rather it has to do with how `hover` is being used to set the display for all items at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can use arrow functions rather than binding the functions with the component.
And you can store the id in viewDescription and viewSummary state to know which item to show description and summary.
Exact details are below ...

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import GoogleSearch from "./GoogleSerach";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchSubjects } from "../../actions/subject";

class Subject extends Component {
  // on loading the subjects will be fetched
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchSubjects();
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      viewDescription: -1,
      viewSummary: -1,
    };
  }

  // add new subject to the top of subjects
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.newPost) {
      this.props.subjects.unshift(nextProps.newPost);
    }
  }

  clickHandler = (id) => {
    const {viewDescription} = this.state; 
    this.setState({ viewDescription: viewDescription === id ? -1 : id });
    console.log("Clicked");
  }

  hoverHandler = (id) => {
    this.setState({ viewSummary: id });
    console.log("Hovered");
  }

  hoverOffHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ viewSummary: -1 });
    console.log("Hovered off");
  }

  render() {
    const subjectItems = this.props.subjects.map((subject) => {
      var view = this.state.viewDescription === subject._id ? "" : "none";
      var hover = this.state.viewSummary === subject._id ? "" : "none";
      return (
        <div key={subject._id}>
          <div
            className="subjectTitle"
            onClick={() => this.clickHandler(subject._id)}
            onMouseEnter={() => this.hoverHandler(subject._id)}
            onMouseLeave={() => this.hoverOffHandler()}
          >
            <p className="title">{subject.title}</p>
            <p className="rating">Rating: {subject.rating}</p>
          </div>

          <p className="summary" style={{ display: hover }}>
            {subject.summary}
          </p>

          <div className="subjectBody " style={{ display: view }}>
            <div className="subjectAuthor">
              <p className="author">
                Subject created by: {subject.author} on {subject.date}
              </p>
              <a href="">
                <div className="buttonRateSubject">RATE SUBJECT</div>
              </a>
            </div>

            <div className="subjectDescription">
              <p className="description">{subject.description}</p>
            </div>

            <div className="subjectLinks">Links:</div>

            <div className="subjectComments">
              <p>Comments:</p>
              <p>{subject.comments}</p>
              <a href="/addcomment">
                <div className="buttonAddComment">ADD COMMENT</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    });

    return (
      <div id="Subject">
        <GoogleSearch />
        {subjectItems}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Subject.propTypes = {
  fetchSubjects: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  subjects: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  newPost: PropTypes.object,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  subjects: state.subjects.items,
  newSubject: state.subjects.item,
});

// export default Subject;
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchSubjects })(Subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is this:

```
 var view = this.state.viewDescription ? "" : "none";
 var hover = this.state.viewSummary ? "" : "none";
```

These two variables are being toggled when one of the items are hovered over, but inside the `map` statement, you have, for example:

```
<p className="summary" style={{ display: hover }}>
```

What this means is that if any of the items are clicked, `this.state.viewSummary` will (if the code is commented back in) get set to true. Hence the `hover` variable will be set to `""`. But this means that *every* item is going to be displayed since  every item will have:

```
<p className="summary" style={{ display: "" }}>
```

Instead of storing a boolean value for `viewSummary`, you may want to store the index in the list or some ID which matches the item that was clicked. That way, you can have everything but that element be set to `display: "none"`.